# Upper bound on r in the aks paper

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-complexity, primality-test

I have been recently reading the paper "PRIMES is in P", but unfortunately a lot of the steps were skipped, which led to confusion. My main problem is with the upper bound on r which was not explained at all in the paper(i don't see the connection of these bounds to the runtime of the algorithm), for example how did they come up with the upper bound O(log^5 n) for r, why is it exactly this number? why not O(log^2 n) or something else. Moreover they had set a condition for r in the second step of the algorithm. They wanted the order of r mod n to be greater than log^2 n, but i don't see why this has anything to do with polynomial runtime or why does it have to be greater than log^2 n.

Can anyone please explain why this is true? or how to derive these numbers?

Comment: The proof in the paper is really simple compared to most other primality proofs. I (and many others) suspect the condition on $ord_r(n) > \log^2(n)$ could be replaced with a bound near $\log n$, but no one has ever shown this. In fact, no one has ever developed a practical version to this test. Given this paper is almost 20 years old, I think it is unlikely that any practical version will arise in the future.

Comment: the existence proof isn't a problem, i just don't get these bounds and where they come from. Did they simply try many bounds (say logn^3, log^4,. ..etc) and deduced that the smallest one is log^2 n?

Comment: looking back at the paper again, It seems that the upper $l$ bound is roughly $\log^2(n)$, but in the proof, that isn't directly stated what $l$ is (p. 787) however, in (p. 789) they substitute the bounds in the algorithm to come to a contradiction. Thus, $\log^3(n)$, $\log^4(n)$,... $\log^k(n)$ would also be sufficient. However, when we try to substitute a bound such as $\log(n)$, this bound doesn't meet the proof requirement, so if the $\log^2(n)$ bound could be reduced, it would require a different (perhaps more extensive) proof. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, without this bound lemma 4.9 would break. Thanks